# Chaining function in rust produce unexpected behaviour

Tags: rust

I am writing a safe wrapper around a c library in rust, and I found a weird behaviour:

```rust
// this works
let string = CString::new(filename).expect("error saving image");
let bytes = string.as_bytes_with_nul();
let ptr = bytes.as_ptr();
let image = unsafe { load_image_color(ptr as *mut c_char, width.into(), height.into()) };

//this panics with "STB Reason: can't fopen" as the string passed seems to be null ("")
let string = CString::new(filename)
    .expect("error loading image")
    .as_bytes_with_nul()
    .as_ptr();
let image = unsafe { load_image_color(string as *mut c_char, width.into(), height.into()) };
```

Can someone please explain to me why these two pieces of code are not semantically equivalent??

Comment: The second piece leads to undefined behavior because the actual string (behind the value of type `CString`) is released right after you obtain a raw pointer to it.

Comment: [It is your responsibility to make sure that the underlying memory is not freed too early.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.as_ptr) You might have meant `into_raw`, not `as_ptr`.